# Why can't I set a Dojo Deferred's property like dojo.store.JsonRest?

Tags: ajax, dojo, deferred

**Why can't I set a (custom user-defined) property of a Deferred object to a promise returned by that same Deferred object?** I think it is possible because [`dojo.store.JsonRest` does it](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.2/dojo-release-1.7.2/dojo/store/JsonRest.js):

```
var results = xhr("GET", {
    url: this.target + (query || ""),
    handleAs: "json",
    headers: headers
});
results.total = results.then(function(){
    var range = results.ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Range");
    return range && (range=range.match(/\/(.*)/)) && +range[1];
});
return QueryResults(results);
```

I have to do something very similar, but I chain on an extra deferred object because I need to transform my JSON input to the format QueryResults() expects. If I assign that promise to a property of my Deferred object, it results in `undefined`. However, if I assign the promise to a regular variable the assignment works. Unfortunately, QueryResults needs the property to be assigned.

I think I have boiled down the problem to a difference between the promises returned by `xhr()` and `xhr().then()`. Please check the console output of [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Leftium/DPrX6/).

**What is the difference, and how can I work around it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward reason why you can't change the property is that the `promise` object [is frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. In essence **the object is made effectively immutable**.

Dojo documentation explains why the promise is frozen:

> The `.then()` call returns a new promise that represents the result of the execution of the callback. **The callbacks will never affect the original promise's value.**

The reason why you can change the property of `Deferred` returned by `xhr()` is that

> The **`dojo.Deferred` is a type of `promise`** that provides methods for fulfilling the promise with a successful result or an error.

Actually, the promise of `Deferred` is stored is Deferred's property `Deferred.promise`, which is also frozen and `Deferred.then()` just links to `Deferred.promise.then()`.

I would not recommend it, but if you insist on changing the `promise` you can achieve it via `lang.delegate()`:

```
my_deferred = lang.delegate(my_deferred);
```

I modified your jsFiddle a bit to clarify the aforementioned: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/N3J7M/.